# Access outer method from inside class

Tags: ruby, scope

Is there any way to access an outer method from inside a class? For example:

Using a .haml file ( therefore inside `class Haml::Engine`), have a `class Tumblr` defined, with a method `self.render`. Outside of the `Tumblr` class, `#haml_concat` functions perfectly, but returns a `NameError` inside `Tumblr`. `#haml_concat` is defined in `Haml::Helpers`. Why is `#haml_concat` unusable inside `Tumblr`?

```
value = 42

class TestClass
  def test_method
    value
  end
end

TestClass.new.value
# should ideally return 42
```

Right now this just returns `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'value' for #<TestClass:0x00000000e24960>`.

Comment: That's not an 'outer method'. value is a local variable, so only accessible from its scope

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify receiver of the method, ruby looking it in the class of the current object and up to all its ancestors.

So, because `Haml::Engine` is not in the list of `Tumblr` ancestors, ruby can't find this method. The solution is to specify object on which you calling method explicitly.

And, do you really define `Tumblr` class inside haml file? It looks like a very bad approach.

Comment: Apologies, I think I've over-simplified the problem. I'm trying to access an outer method which is defined in a Module, while also allowing for the Class; I'll edit the question.