# Using haml_tag, haml_concat from within class?

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm defining a `class` within Haml, and I'd like to be able to use the Haml helpers from within this class. For example:

```
- class Whatever
  - def self.write
    - haml_concat "something"

- Whatever.write
```

Ideally, `Whatever.write` would output `"something"` to the template, but it simply fails with `undefined method 'haml_concat' for Haml::Engine::Whatever:Class`.

Full stacktrace:

```
haml_test.haml:5:in `write': undefined method `haml_concat' for Haml::Engine::Whatever:Class (NoMethodError)
    from haml_test.haml:8:in `block in render'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/engine.rb:191:in `eval'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/engine.rb:191:in `render'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/exec.rb:281:in `process_result'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/lib/haml/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/haml-3.1.4/bin/haml:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/haml:19:in `load'
    from /home/fraser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/haml:19:in `<main>'
```

How can I get this to work properly? I've tried using both `extend` and `include` `Haml::Helpers`, but they both fail too. Any ideas?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to define a class inside your Haml? Haml is for ... wait for it ... templates and markup!

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing in the haml context. I have no idea if this will work, of if it does if it will suit your purpose, but it's an idea (I don't have the means to test it).

```
- class Whatever
  - def self.write(ctx)
    - ctx.haml_concat "something"

- Whatever.write(self)
```

If this does work (again, I really don't know), you could also try passing in the context as a Whatever class-level instance variable so you can use your Whatever writer without having to pass in the haml context every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- @self = self
- class Whatever
  - def self.write
    - @self.haml_concat "something"

- Whatever.write
```

But, [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627658/986282), HAML is a markup language, and you shouldn't declare classes inside it. Also it is contrary to the principles of MVC.

Comment: I'm entirely aware that Haml is markup, but I'm relatively sure that this is the best way to solve my problem. Still getting `undefined method 'haml_concat' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` though.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be easier to pass the thing itself?

```
= "something #{@my_object.my_method}"
= @my_object.my_other_method
```

What am I missing?  I'm unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to be able to pass blocks and have them properly indented, which means I need `tab_down` and `tab_up`. I'm not using Rails.

Comment: I think I see.  Are you trying to dynamically pass a block?

Comment: Yup. I need to be able to do stuff like `Whatever.tab do Whatever.write end`, where `Whatever.tab`: `tab_up; yield; tab_down`.